# Can PNG images contain embedded thumbnails like JPG files?

Tags: jpeg, png, thumbnails, image-editing

Can PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image files contain embedded thumbnails similar to how JPG files can?

Comment: I can't find the word "thumbnail" in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/)

Comment: [Does PNG contain EXIF data like JPG?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9542359)

Answer (score 5):

You can put a thumbnail image in the Exif profile, then store the Exif profile in a PNG eXIf chunk, if you are using libpng-1.6.32 or later.

Comment: Can you add a few sentences to explain how to accomplish that (assuming it's a simple command in any image software and not a custom programming task)?  Thanks.